# Using Converters in WINRT applications

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro

I am developing a WINRT metro style application using c# and XAML.
I want to use Converters in my WINRT application in so many situations. Using converters is more convenient for me, but my question is "Is there any disadvantages for using Converters , like memory usage..etc" Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disadvantages when using converters can be:

1. Code scattering - some parts of your application logic might be located in your converter classes.
2. Inflexibility - converters can only bind to a single property by default, you also can't databind the converterparameter argument. This might become a problem if you want to show values that are computed from multiple input values.

I would try to use an [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj651572.aspx) architecture and get rid of most converters. Only use them for simple conversions like bool to Visibility.